# Kinect blinking skeleton

Tags: c#, wpf, kinect

I am writing game in WPF using Kinect.
I have a problem with blinking skeleton. I have noticed that it only blinks when the other window is under this with skeleton. If the skeleton window is the only one displaying then everything works perfect.

Situation:
1st window with menu. Then I add UserControl with configuration screen (for game) on the 1st window. From the configuration screen after hitting a button new 2nd window is created (that with skeleton).

I don't want to have two windows active at the same time. I have tried to minimize the 1st window but every try failed. Please give me solution how properly minimize window in that situation or find any other way how to remove blinking Kinect skeleton.

EDIT:
I have edited my project that there is only one window. The game using skeleton is now UserControl that is added to MainWindow as a Children. The problem still exists. Nothing has changed.

Comment: Is there a design reason you are using two windows?  It would be cleaner experience for the user, and for the code base, to keep everything in one window (using an MVVM model if you want to separate code appropriately).  That would seem to solve a few problems, including the skeleton issue, all at once.

Comment: It was a project design to have every game as a new separate project that can be run itself. And than every project can be added  to my main Solution and built in a one bigger game. I didn't know that it could make a problem like this.